# How to get specific strings based on complex pattern with, regular expression

Tags: r, string

```
path<-c("C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/argentina-primera-division-matches-2022-to-2022-stats.csv",
"C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/argentina-primera-division-matches-2022-to-2022-stats.csv",
"C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/france-ligue-2-matches-2021-to-2022-stats.csv",
"C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/germany-2-bundesliga-matches-2021-to-2022-stats.csv")

mydata<-data.frame(path=path)
```

I want to create new variables out of variable `path`

`Country` the pattern is: `DONNEES/country name` -`

`League` the pattern is: `DONNEES/` `a word` - `League name` `-matches`

`Year` the pattern is: `-` `The year` `-to`

This should the resulting dataset:

```
                                                                                                                     path   Country           League Year
1 C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/argentina-primera-division-matches-2022-to-2022-stats.csv argentina primera-division 2022
2 C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/argentina-primera-division-matches-2022-to-2022-stats.csv argentina primera-division  202
3             C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/france-ligue-2-matches-2021-to-2022-stats.csv    france          ligue-2 2021
4       C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/germany-2-bundesliga-matches-2021-to-2022-stats.csv   germany     2-bundesliga 2021
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `extract` to capture the word after the `DONNEES/`, followed by the `-`, capture the characters (`.*`) before the `-matches-` and the year part as 4 digits (`\\d{4}`)

```
library(tidyr)
extract(mydata, path, into = c("Country", "League", "Year"),
     ".*DONNEES/(\\w+)-(.*)-matches-(\\d{4})-.*", remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
                                                                                                                     path   Country
1 C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/argentina-primera-division-matches-2022-to-2022-stats.csv argentina
2 C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/argentina-primera-division-matches-2022-to-2022-stats.csv argentina
3             C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/france-ligue-2-matches-2021-to-2022-stats.csv    france
4       C:/Users/SEYDOU GORO/Dropbox/PC (2)/Documents/BETCLIC/DONNEES/germany-2-bundesliga-matches-2021-to-2022-stats.csv   germany
            League Year
1 primera-division 2022
2 primera-division 2022
3          ligue-2 2021
4     2-bundesliga 2021
```